# Trying to add lists of lists to an empty dictionary in a for loop, but the entries are being completely overwritten in every iteration

Tags: python, debugging, dictionary, element, abaqus

Novice with programming in general here. I have an empty dictionary with no number of keys, (where no in this case = 3). I'm trying to generate a list of lists that will be added to the dictionary within a loop, but over each loop the other keys are being overwritten. See my attempt below:

```
#generating dictionary for all fibres with number n 
fibre = {i : {}for i in range(no)}
#generating empty fibre of size n_f
fibre_e = [[[] for i in range(n_f)] for j in range(n_f)]
rand_r = [[] for a in range(no)]
rand_c = [[] for a in range(no)]

#generating fibre element from random corner elements
for a in range(no):
    # choosing a random corner element
    fibre[a] = fibre_e
    rand_r[a] = randrange(len(all_e))
    rand_c[a] = randrange(len(all_e))

    for i in range(n_f):
        e1_fibre=all_e[rand_r[a]][rand_c[a]]
        #move to upper row
        rand_r[a] += 1
        for j in range(n_f):
            fibre_e[i][j] = e1_fibre
            e1_fibre += 1

    print(fibre)
```

This is the output when I checked the progression:

```
{0: [[57, 58], [66, 67]], 1: {}, 2: {}}
{0: [[33, 34], [42, 43]], 1: [[33, 34], [42, 43]], 2: {}}
{0: [[29, 30], [38, 39]], 1: [[29, 30], [38, 39]], 2: [[29, 30], [38, 39]]}
```

For context, this is to generate an abaqus mesh file with a random distribution of identical fibre elements within a matrix.

edit:context

---

Using copy.deepcopy worked

```
for a in range(no):
    # choosing a random corner element

    rand_r[a] = randrange(len(all_e))
    rand_c[a] = randrange(len(all_e))

    for i in range(n_f):
        e1_fibre=all_e[rand_r[a]][rand_c[a]]
        #move to upper row
        rand_r[a] += 1
        for j in range(n_f):
            fibre_e[i][j] = e1_fibre
            e1_fibre += 1
            fibre[a] = copy.deepcopy(fibre_e)

    print(fibre)
```

Output:

```
{0: [[68, 69], [77, 78]], 1: {}, 2: {}}
{0: [[68, 69], [77, 78]], 1: [[6, 7], [15, 16]], 2: {}}
{0: [[68, 69], [77, 78]], 1: [[6, 7], [15, 16]], 2: [[28, 29], [37, 38]]}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/8586227

Comment: thank you. copy.deepcopy worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Specifically in your case, just assign the *expression* you're assigning to `fibre_e` to `fibre[a]` instead.  Then new lists get created for each iteration.  (You don't need the variable `fibre_e` then at all.)